# Why do 1st index is overriding in javascript array when 2nd index is added?

Tags: javascript

For example when I text the following code, the answer is **10**

```
var testArry = [20, 10, 90, 50, 66][1];
console.log(testArry); // output: 10
```

When i add another index the first index is overriding, the answer is **90**

```
var testArry = [20, 10, 90, 50, 66][1,2];
console.log(testArry); // output: 90
```

What is the reason for overriding? Is this overriding or any other terminology is there for this?

I googled it but not found the desired reason.

Thanks.

Comment: `1,2` evaluates to 2.  `1,3,4,5,10` evalutes to 10.  The last expression executed is the return value.

Answer (score 1):

In your array index expression (the 1,2) you are using the comma operator, which simply returns the last result, in this case a two, and does nothing with the others (the 1). Therefore you're basically just writing `testArray[2]`.

Comment: Additional notes: Basically, it is just using the last value. If you had [1,2,3] 3 is used resulting in 50. If you specified 8 as the last value then the results would be undefined as the index would be out of bound.